# How to add objects to a hasMany relationship with ember data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have these two models:

```
App.Items = DS.Model.extend({
    provider: DS.attr('string'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
});

App.Baskets = DS.Model.extend({
    selectedItems: DS.hasMany('App.Items'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    username: DS.attr('string'),
})
```

Now what I want to do is add a new Item to a Basket when a user selects it. I have tried to do this:

```
basket = App.Baskets.find(1);
item = App.Items.find(1);
basket.set("selectedItems", item)  ; 
App.store.commit();
```

This doesn't return any errors but it doesn't trigger any requests to the server.

Alternatively, I have tried this:

```
basket = App.Baskets.find(1);
selectedItems = basket.get("selectedItems")
selectedItems.pushObject(App.Items.find(1))
App.store.commit();
```

This method returns an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined ember.js:1691
get ember.js:1691
DS.OneToManyChange.sync ember-data.js:4572
(anonymous function) ember-data.js:424
OrderedSet.forEach ember.js:1410
DS.ManyArray.DS.RecordArray.extend.arrayContentDidChange ember-data.js:423
newFunc ember.js:1167
Ember.ArrayProxy.Ember.Object.extend.arrangedContentArrayDidChange ember.js:10600
sendEvent ember.js:3792
Ember.Array.Ember.Mixin.create.arrayContentDidChange ember.js:7933
Ember.Mixin.create.replace ember.js:11011
Ember.ArrayProxy.Ember.Object.extend.replaceContent ember.js:10476
DS.ManyArray.DS.RecordArray.extend.replaceContent ember-data.js:351
newFunc ember.js:1167
Ember.ArrayProxy.Ember.Object.extend.replace ember.js:10591
Ember.MutableArray.Ember.Mixin.create.insertAt ember.js:8398
Ember.MutableArray.Ember.Mixin.create.pushObject ember.js:8450
App.Router.Ember.Router.extend.root.Ember.Route.extend.items.Ember.Route.extend.savePreferences dashboard-app.js:218
sendRecursively ember.js:17303
sendEvent ember.js:17320
Ember.StateManager.Ember.State.extend.send ember.js:17845
ActionHelper.registeredActions.(anonymous function).handler ember.js:22673
(anonymous function) ember.js:13009
Ember.handleErrors ember.js:379
(anonymous function) ember.js:13003
v.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:2
o.handle.u
```

The weird things is that when I try to set a normal attribute of the same model, let's say set the name of the basket, everything works fine. Ember data fires a PUT request to the server and my model is updated. So obviously then problem is when I update a relationship. Am I doing this the wrong way or is it an ember data bug?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your code is failing because in the current version of Ember Data you have to specify an inverse to every relationship.

```
App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
    provider: DS.attr('string'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    basket: DS.belongsTo('App.Basket')
});

App.Basket = DS.Model.extend({
    items: DS.hasMany('App.Item'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    username: DS.attr('string'),
})

basket = App.Basket.find(1);
basket.get("items").pushObject(App.Item.find(1));
App.store.commit();
```

Check out the issues on Github for more details.

Particularly the WIP on relationships with inverse:null and manyToMany.

Comment: An item can have many baskets .i.e it can be selected by more than basket. That means I need a many to many relationship. I was under the impression that ManyToMany relationships were not supported yet.

Comment: Exactly, inverse:null and manytomany are both still in planning. Hopefully with your application one user has one basket so you can treat it as a one-to-many relation on the client?

Comment: One user can have multiple baskets but I guess I can model it that way for now. Is that why my code is failing? Due to the missing inverse relationship? Also, which of the methods I mentioned above is the correct way to add a new object to a hasMany relationship?

Comment: Updated the answer, yes the missing inverse is causing the error. `pushObject` is the best way to add an existing object to a ManyArray

Comment: Great. That fixed the previous problem. Thanks a lot. The only problem now is that only a PUT request to the Items endpoint is triggered. It only updates one side of the relationship. Basket never gets updated when I commit.

Comment: Which is the expected response for a hasMany-belongsTo relationship, I guess it wasn't quite as easy as just pretending the manytomany didn't exist. Personally I'd just add a hasMany relationship in the opposite direction at the same time, but that'd be heading down a very dangerous path

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.